# How to query for delete the same data out of the table?

Tags: sql

[image: I want the output to look like this.]

I want to delete it for the output to look like this. In one group there should be only 1 user_id.

```
select distinct group_id, user_id, count(*)
from pin_users
where group_id in (select group_id from pin_users)
group by group_id, user_id
having count(*) > 1
```

I get all user_id, group_id and count more than 1 but I don't know how to delete duplicates and leave only 1 left.

Ps. My English is probably not perfect, pls excuse any mistakes

Comment: Which Database are you using?

Comment: Which logic is to be used to determine which row to be left in the table?

Comment: Which row do you want to select when there are "duplicates"? That row having the minimum id?

Comment: You should also point out if you want to do a query or really to delete data, please.

Comment: A `select distinct` combined with `group by` raises many eyebrows. (The GROUP BY has already eliminated all duplicates.)

Comment: @Abinash PostgreSQL sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a subquery to get a list of minimum ids for any combination of users and groups. Then remove everything else.

```
DELETE FROM pin_users WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT min(id) as id
    FROM pin_users
    GROUP BY group_id, user_id
)
```

Comment: Please tick and Upvote if it solved your issue 

Answer (score 0):

In case of `sql-server`, try this:

```
-- mockup data
declare @Raw table (
    id nvarchar(max),
    group_id nvarchar(max),
    user_id nvarchar(max)
                   )

insert into @Raw values ('p001', 'aaa', 'ava001'), ('p002', 'aaa', 'ava001'), ('p003', 'bbb', 'ava001'), ('p004', 'bbb', 'ava001');

-- check this query
with A as (
    select id, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by group_id, user_id order by id) as RN 
from @Raw)
delete from @Raw where id in (select id from A where A.RN > 1)

-- verify table
select * from @Raw
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, with sql server should be something like this

```
delete u1
from pin_users u1
 join (
   select min(id) id, group_id, user_id
   from pin_users
   group by group_id, user_id
   ) u2
   on u1.group_id = u2.group_id
  and u1.user_id = u2.user_id
  and u1.id <> u2.id
```